# Customize text email in PHP Using web services

Tags: php, iphone, web-services

I want to send an email to the user who register using my application.

I am using following code to send email to my usesr using web services.

My message contain :

```
PARA 1
PARA 2 
PARA 3

$message = "WWOW THIS IS PARA 1. THIS IS PARA 2. THIS IS PARA 3"
$this->Mail($email, "Register Success", $message);

    function Mail($to, $subject, $message) 
    {
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: xxxx! <registration@xxxx.com>' . "\r\n";

        // Mail it
        if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            throw new Exception('There was a problem trying to send an email.');
        }
    }
```

However i want to customize the text as lets say ,  in Verdana 11px dark grey font. How can I do this and form them in PARA. My para does contain quotes, and colons and commas too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the email can be html.
make it all html.

```
$message = "<html><body><p style=\"ffont: verdanna 11px\">".$PARA1."<br/>".$PARA2."<br/>".$PARA3."<br/></p></body></html>";
```

typed inline -- no guarantees for typos and or valid CSS!